# Split Media Queries in different files!

Tags: functions, css, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-style

I woke up this morning with a thought. 
Is it a good idea to split the different media queries in different files, check the width of the page in functions.php and then with an IF call the "correct" using `wp_register_style` and `wp_enqueue_style`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no functions in wordpress that checks or determine screen sizes. These are all browser related stuff that has got nothing to do with wordpress. There are jquery functions that can maybe work, but again, this is not wordpress related. `wp_is_mobile` can be used to load stuff conditionally for mobile phones, but then again, `wp_is_mobile` don't have the logic determining screen sizes, it also can't differentiate between things like mobile phones and tablets.

Your solution here is to do it old school, using media queries in your main stylesheet as done in all of the default themes shipped with wordpress.

Closing off, I would most probably think that if there was such functions to determine screen sizes in wordpress, that it would be completely overrated and useless and time wasting just to load something simple like a stylesheet

Comment: Hahaha, such thoughs are never BAD. Glad I could help though

Comment: It was to keep the code more clean! :)
Thank you again and not have 200000 lines in one css file